# google app engine deployment with joomla 3.2.1

Tags: php, google-app-engine, joomla

I am having several issues with deploying my site once it is done locally.One of the issues is as follows. A snippet frommy log. The mimetype cannot be correctly found from the files.

```
    INFO     2014-03-17 12:24:56,210 shutdown.py:44] Shutting down.
INFO     2014-03-17 12:24:56,298 api_server.py:538] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2014-03-17 12:24:56,298 api_server.py:541] Saving search indexes

*** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
    --no_cookies --email=richaccs@gmail.com --passin update
01:24 PM Application: fit-rig-517; version: 1-0-test
01:24 PM Host: appengine.google.com
01:24 PM 
Starting update of app: fit-rig-517, version: 1-0-test
01:24 PM Getting current resource limits.
01:25 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/system/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/system/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/system/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/system/offline.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/system/html/modules.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/less/icomoon.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/less/template.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/less/variables.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_protostar.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_protostar.sys.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/html/modules.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/protostar/html/pagination.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/jsstrings.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_beez3.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_beez3.sys.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/message.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/modules.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/mod_login/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/mod_breadcrumbs/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/form/edit.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/category/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/category/default_children.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/category/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/categories/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_weblinks/categories/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_newsfeeds/category/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_newsfeeds/category/default_children.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_newsfeeds/category/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_newsfeeds/categories/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_newsfeeds/categories/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/form/edit.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/featured/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/featured/default_item.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/featured/default_links.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_children.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/blog_links.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/default_articles.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/category/default_children.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/categories/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/categories/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/article/default_links.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/archive/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_content/archive/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default_address.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default_articles.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default_form.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default_links.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/default_profile.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/contact/encyclopedia.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/category/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/category/default_children.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/category/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/categories/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/html/com_contact/categories/default_items.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for templates/beez3/css/turq.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
01:25 PM Scanned 500 files.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/accordion.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/alerts.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/bootstrap-extended.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/bootstrap-rtl.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/bootstrap.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/breadcrumbs.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/button-groups.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/buttons.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/carousel.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/close.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/code.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/component-animations.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/dropdowns.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/forms.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/grid.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/hero-unit.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/icomoon.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/labels-badges.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/layouts.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/media.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/mixins.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/modals.joomla.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/modals.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/navbar.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/navs.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/pager.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/pagination.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/popovers.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/progress-bars.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/reset.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-1200px-min.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-767px-max.joomla.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-767px-max.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-768px-979px.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-navbar.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive-utilities.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/responsive.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/scaffolding.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/sprites.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/tables.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/thumbnails.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/tooltip.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/type.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/utilities.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/variables.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/jui/less/wells.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
01:25 PM Scanned 1000 files.
Could not guess mimetype for media/editors/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/readme.md.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for media/editors/tinymce/langs/readme.md.  Using application/octet-stream.
01:25 PM Scanned 1500 files.
01:25 PM Scanned 2000 files.
01:25 PM Scanned 2500 files.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/system/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/system/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/system/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/system/html/modules.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/cpanel.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/login.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/less/icomoon.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/less/template-rtl.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/less/template.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/less/variables.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_isis.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_isis.sys.ini.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/html/message.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/html/modules.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/html/pagination.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/isis/html/mod_version/default.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/component.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/cpanel.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/error.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/index.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/login.php.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/less/buttons.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/less/colour_baseline.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/less/colour_blue.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for administrator/templates/hathor/less/colour_brown.less.  Using application/octet-stream.
```

On searching around on this site I found a few vartions on what to do. I have attempted to include a mime type line in my app.yaml file. This removed the log errors however After deployment I found now I had a 500 internal error. Here's my app.yaml file.

```
application: fit-rig-517
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: joomla/\1
  upload: joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

## Admin  
- url: /administrator(.+)
  script: joomla/administrator\1

## Asset folders
- url: /media
  static_dir: joomla/media
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: text/html

- url: /images
  static_dir: joomla/images
  application_readable: true

## Template folders
- url: /templates
  static_dir: joomla/templates
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: application/(htm$|html$|css$|js$)

- url: /administrator/templates
  static_dir: joomla/administrator/templates
  application_readable: true
  mime_type: text/html

## SEO robots
- url: /robots.txt
  script: joomla/robots.txt 

## Site access
- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: joomla/index.php
```

any help much appreciated
Richard

Here is my application log;

```
2014-03-18 04:12:04.408 /favicon.ico 500 597ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 module=default version=1 
    [18/Mar/2014:04:12:04 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" "fit-rig-517.appspot.com" ms=598 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 pending_ms=295 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117c12cd92538ca7e793538ae645c125

    I 2014-03-18 04:12:04.408

    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

    W 2014-03-18 04:12:04.408

    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

     2014-03-18 04:12:04.098 / 500 327ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 module=default version=1 
    [18/Mar/2014:04:12:04 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" "fit-rig-517.appspot.com" ms=327 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117c41e50787535d999f11c7593db554c8

    I 2014-03-18 04:12:04.097

    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

    W 2014-03-18 04:12:04.097

    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)


     2014-03-18 04:12:03.528 / 500 469ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 module=default version=1 
    [18/Mar/2014:04:12:03 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0" "fit-rig-517.appspot.com" ms=469 cpu_ms=0 loading_request=1 exit_code=204 app_engine_release=1.9.0 instance=00c61b117c0581701767516f0f70cef37ced3c71

    I 2014-03-18 04:12:03.528

    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

    W 2014-03-18 04:12:03.528

    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)
```

Comment: Mind to share the error log? Thanks.

Comment: @Mars i added about 50% of the error log. I have a limit on size. It mostly revolves around the same mime-type error. I have tried various things by adding mime-type: text/css or text/html or application/javascript and this removes all of the mime-type errors. However I still have a 500 error on deployment! this never goes away

Comment: I assume you're getting a 500 error on your app, not on the deployment process itself? In that case, could you also share your app's error log (from the GAE admin console)

Comment: @Mars i added my application error log: I hope this is what you meant. All these 3 points in the log are marked as Info or Warning as opposed to Errors though

Comment: It seems that the runtime crashed before having a chance to output anything meaningful to the log. I assume you've verified that the app works locally using the SDK right?

Comment: @Mars yes, locally the app works fine. It is a joomla 3 app. I have had the Mime-type problems in deployment contiually but i can get it to work. the css file for example sometimes is sent as text/plain and sometimes text/css. I never get a white screen or 500 error though.

Comment: Could you try to get a simple hello world or phpinfo to work under your current setting? Also did you put anything special in your php.ini, like loading an extension?